# Does Windows 8 support UTC as BIOS time?

Tags: bios, windows-8, utc

Is there any way to use Windows 8 with time in UTC in BIOS? I know there is a way to do it in Windows 7 (in this question: [Does Windows 7 support UTC as BIOS time?](https://superuser.com/questions/185773)), but this solution makes my system unbootable.

Windows expects the bios clock to be set to local time by default. In Windows 7 and before, there was a registry hack to change this behavior so that it could expect UTC – is there an equivalent in Windows 8?

Comment: I think the answer will be similar to your previous post: http://superuser.com/questions/185773/does-windows-7-support-utc-as-bios-time

Comment: possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/494432/force-windows-8-to-use-utc-when-dealing-with-bios-clock

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes. Just follow these steps:

1. Open `regedit`.
2. Navigate to the following key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`
3. Right-click in the white area and select `New --> DWORD (32-bit Value)`
4. Name the key `RealTimeIsUniversal`.
5. Double-click on it and set its value to 1.

Answer (score 17):

@Zuck's answer is fine, but much quicker via the [Command Line Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) (CLI).

Open up [`cmd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) as Administrator then run:

```
reg ADD HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation /t REG_DWORD /v RealTimeIsUniversal /d 1
```