# Force Windows 8 to use UTC when dealing with BIOS clock

Tags: windows-8, bios

I have Arch Linux + Windows 8 on my laptop.  In previous versions of Windows, there is a DWORD in the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\RealTimeIsUniversal`) that switches between localtime and UTC, but this doesn't seem to be working in Windows 8 anymore.

I am now getting UTC time in Windows since it thinks BIOS gives it localtime which is actually UTC time, and after reboot into Arch Linux, the clock becomes localtime-0400, because Arch thinks BIOS is having the correct UTC time.

I do not want to let Arch Linux use localtime.  Under this prerequisite, is there any possible solution?

Comment: The RealTimeIsUniversal key worked fine for me, dual booting Arch Linux also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RealTimeIsUniversal is really buggy and *not* an officially recommended solution (maybe that's why they disabled it in Win8?) See [IBM PC Real Time Clock should run in UT](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/mswish/ut-rtc.html) and a response from Raymond Chen here: [Why does Windows keep your BIOS clock on local time?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040902-00/?p=37983). As of date I don't think there's a proper solution for this.

Comment: buggy? never had any problems with it, and forcing windows to use a UTC system clock really is the only sane solution. and the key is *not* disabled in win8. real solution is to set the registry key, turn off windows’ time sync, and let linux handle the syncing if you boot there often enough.

Comment: @flyingsheep Over the years a few hotfixes have been released, see *Current support status in Windows* on http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/mswish/ut-rtc.html

Comment: @Stijn Great link, I think you should make it into an answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 16):

The default Windows Time service will always write local time to the hardware clock on shutdown, regardless of what the registry says about the real time being in UTC. Outside of this caveat, Windows will treat the hardware time clock correctly, if the registry is set correctly. Try this:

1. If the time is messed up from trying to get Windows to use UTC, boot into Windows, and set the time as it would be normally (correct timezone, no regedit, Windows Time service enabled, recently synced, etc)
2. Do the regedit you mentioned already
3. Sync the time `w32tm /config /update`
4. Disable Windows Time service `sc config w32time start= disabled`
5. Install a 3rd party NTP client
6. Verify that it works with a reboot

Comment: Just set this up myself after having Windows set the clock on each shutdown. Found the following NTP software for Windows which is very easy to setup and configure. http://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm

Comment: That software seems to be a repackaging of the official NTP distribution, with some extras. Anyway, I used it and also found it to work.

Comment: After you create the registry key, it may take a few days before it has any effect. At least this was the case for me and a friend of mine. It did not work at first but randomly started working after a few days. Maybe one restart is enough after you disable "fast startup", but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 15):

`RealTimeIsUniversal` registry key **still works** in Windows 8 and 10! The instructions to use this method are explained lot of times everywhere, for example in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/497666/210811).

I will replicate the answer here:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, `regedit`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Navigate to the key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`.
3. Create new DWORD (32-bit) Value, name it `RealTimeIsUniversal`.
4. Set its value to `1`.

After this is done, just reboot your machine. After it is up and running again, let Windows set time automatically (click on the current time in tray, `Date and Time Settings` > `Set Time Automatically`), this time it will not mess with it.

Comment: Some say that it should be a QWORD on 64-bit systems, so FYI: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/System_time#Dual_booting_with_Windows

Comment: Is there any way to reload  this registry key without reboot windows ?

Answer (score 0):

@jiehanzheng yes, if you use NTP in Windows, it will mess up the clock. Sounds like the best workaround is to run NTP in whatever flavor of *NIX you're dual booting, disable NTP in Windows, and offset using whatever time zone you need to.
Then you just have to adjust daylight savings time manually with a time zone shift in Windows, but eh..

Answer (score 0):

`RealTimeIsUniversal` works for me.
To get it to work, after applying the registry entry, *shut down* Windows (not sleep or hibernate).
Boot machine & enter BIOS before booting into Windows, change the time in BIOS, save, then continue booting into Windows.
Alternatively, after shutting down Windows, boot into Linux & let time sync do its job.
If time is updated from within Windows, Windows will somehow update an incorrect time to the system after a reboot.

Comment: Could you link to sources that explain RealTimeIsUniversal?  I didn't know what it was until you mentioned it, and from a number of results, it looks like it comes with its own set of potentially negative side-effects.

Answer (score -1):

RealTimeIsUniversal worked for me in Windows 10.  And at mid-December 2016, it's working for my Windows 7 Pro as well, without rebooting into Linux.

Answer (score -4):

You could just set your time-zone four hours off.

[image]

Comment: Smart workaround...  but the hardware and system clock will be messed up again when I use NTP (Internet Time), right?