# Disable system time synchronisation

Tags: windows-8, sync, time

My system clock (which I can modify in UEFI) is working OK, but three hours behind me.  It's always UTC+00, and changing it is useless because it often resets when my notebook runs out of battery.

I just want to know how I can make Windows 8.1 STOP syncing with it each boot?

I pressed <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, gone to Metro-UI settings and disabled "Set time automatically" setting but it still does it.

I also disabled the "synchronize time over internets" setting but still no effect. Can I change something in the registry to fix it?

Comment: If your system clock is wrong, and keeps getting reset when your battery dies, wouldn't you *want* to have network time synchronization? Otherwise your clock is always wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @Xen2050 I'll tell you why: 1)because I spend a lot of time offline 2) because even if I haven't it just doesnt work automatically! To sync it I have to EACH time go to the internet_time_sync tab in the settings and press `update now`!

Comment: wouldn't the fix be to get a new CMOS battery?

Comment: @Tetsujin Why spend money on something I don't need at all? I don't want to void warranty (by doing it myself) and I'm not going to pay some cunning a-holes $100 for doing that with replacing the seal.

Comment: @mekkanizer Please mind the tone of both your comments *and* questions. We require that all users address each other in civil terms and [be nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice).  Specifically "**Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you." and "**Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.**".  People are trying to help you, there is no need at all for the language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `regedit`

Navigate to the following key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`

Right-click in the white area and select New --> DWORD (32-bit Value)

Name the key `RealTimeIsUniversal`

Double-click on it and set its value to 1.

source:
https://superuser.com/a/552275/406980
https://superuser.com/a/497666/406980