# How to triple boot OS X, WINDOWS, AND KORORA (fedora)

Tags: linux, windows, macos, multi-boot

Background: I believe this is a mac book pro 2013 with 500gb not 100% sure

My friend was dual booting mac and Windows and decided he wanted Linux. He asked me which ui looked the best and I thought personally korora looked the best, so I recommended it. He liked it and so I put it on a USB and began installing it. Fedora uses anaconda to install. After installing it with the correct partitions, we started up the computer and hit options key. This is where it got weird

We only saw two hard drives, mac and Linux efi (I think that's what it was called)

We chose to boot off of the mac drive just to make sure everything worked, however when the apple logo went away after the loading, there was a circle with a cross. We found this weird and thought it must be in Linux drive because we thought it had grub 2. Keep in mind boot camp disappeared. We clicked on Linux drive on the second restart and there was a black screen with two options for korora and two options for Mac. When trying to boot using the mac options, it will not work saying it was the wrong command or something. However, korora booted finefine, and if you went to files, you could see bootcamp and Mac drives as well is korora.

My question to you is: How can we get the boot manager to show OS X, Windows and Linux and be able to boot them.

My belief was the grub wasn't the default bootloader because we ran a test to change the background image on grub and it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you borked the machine, next time use rEFInd => http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/.  Boot to recovery and fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm codemonk113's comment, I use rEFInd for all multi-boots.

Make also up your mind on the BIOS-time. OS X, Windows and Linux do not use the same base in their standard settings. I use UTC-time in BIOS.

Windows needs an entry (See: [Force Windows 8 to use UTC when dealing with BIOS clock](https://superuser.com/questions/494432/force-windows-8-to-use-utc-when-dealing-with-bios-clock)).

OS X needs to get set by a link:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime
```

Linux is fine with UTC, you normally get asked during setup if localtime or UTC.