# Windows 8 is reseting time after set to UTC

Tags: windows-8, clock, time-zone, utc

I [changed timezone like suggest in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/482860/does-windows-8-support-utc-as-bios-time)

But every hour Windows is reseting the time.

I disabled sync from internet but the problem continues

How can I solve that error?

[image: capture of my utc configuration]

Comment: Which answer specifically?

Comment: How can I solved? Prevent that time reset every hour

Comment: Simply changing the time zone always worked for me

Comment: But is not working for me. For that this question. Have any idea why pass this?

Comment: You have not supplied enough information me to even guess at the reason.  I can simply change the timezone to UTC on my system.

Comment: I only do the process how is suggest in the link in the question and after restart every hour the time is reset.... my timezone is set to UTC-4....

Comment: A screenshot of your clock settings would be appreciated.  You say you followed the process but I asked an hour ago, which answer, there are two.

Comment: Just click `date and time settings` then select, `Coordinated Universal TIme`, should be that simple.

Comment: can't see the option that you mention.... I view all options available in the window that I share but I didn't find the option to Coordinated Universal TIme... I only have option to timezone...