# Dual booting Debian / Windows XP: clock is off

Tags: windows-xp, debian, time, time-zone

I just installed Debian (Wheezy) on a Windows XP machine and am dual booting. But the clock is different! It's one hour late on XP versus Debian.

I'm in Paris (GMT +1) and we're in winter (daylight saving time).

I believe I set the time correctly in Debian but I'm not sure. Is it possible that Windows detects the daylight savings time and not Debian?

How to set it correctly so that I don't need to change the clock every time I change OSses?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that Debian actually changes system lock to UTC and then adjust its *display* the user desired timezone. XP on the other hand changes system lock to your desired timezone.

Take a look at this answer for info how to change your Debian timezone [Changing timezone on Debian keeps Local Time in UTC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76710/changing-timezone-on-debian-keeps-local-time-in-utc)

Comment: That is correct: PC BIOSes have no concept of UTC vs local time and just store a timestamp, uninterpreted. Both OSes might be configured to interpret BIOS time as either UTC or localtime -- the Windows configuration is explained [here](http://superuser.com/a/185780/130459).  The only "trick" is that both dual-bootes OSes just should agree on the same interpretation.  The difference is that Debian's installer *defaults* to UTC while Windows installer defaults to local time.

Comment: Another point of interest is that when you're setting up a virtual machine in the VirtualBox GUI, its setting for the BIOS time interpretation will depend on the selected OS flavor: for Linux it will be UTC and for Windows it will be localtime.